# Check if property type overloads == operator with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, code-injection, cil, mono.cecil

I am using `Mono.Cecil` to write a program that injects some `IL` code into property setters. The problem is i need to use equality operator on property to within the `IL`. For example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int _property1;

    public int Property1 
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set { _property1 = value; }
    }

    private string _property2;

    public string Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set { _property2 = value; }
    }
}
```

And `IL` code i need do inject in those setters is something like:

```
if (value != _property1)
{
   //DO SOME STUFF
}
```

Same goes for `Property2`. The problem is that `Property2` is of type `string` which overloads `==` operator and in `IL` instead of `ceq` code i need to call `op_Equality`. My question is: Is there any way to check if `==` operator is overridden on property type using `Mono.Cecil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's actually easy.
I've created a class

```
 public class Foo
    {
        public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b)
        {
            if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return a == b;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Foo a, Foo b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }
    }
```

Compiled it and looked at it in mono.cecil

```
 AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path);
            foreach (var item in assembly.Modules)
            {
                foreach (var type in item.Types)
                {
                    foreach (var method in type.Methods)
                    {
                        if (method.IsStatic && method.IsSpecialName && method.IsPublic && method.Name.Contains("op_Equality"))
                        {
                            //that type overides == operator
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. :) My problem was that i had `FieldDefinition` object and it's property `FieldType` didn't have property `Methods`, so i couldn't check like that. I solved problem with `FieldDefinition.FieldType.Resolve()` method which returned `TypeDefinition` object and then was easy to chek `op_Equality` existence. :)